# Не работает программа, выдает ошибку

Tags: c, циклы

Два натуральных числа называют дружественными, если каждое из них равно сумме всех делителей другого, кроме самого этого числа. Найти все пары дружественных чисел, лежащих в диапазоне от 0 до 300

выдает ошибку "exited, floating point exception"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
int i,j,ai=1,bj=1;
int sum1=0;
int sum2=0;
for ( i = 1; i <300; i++)
{
  for ( j = 1; j <300; j++)
  {
    for (ai = 1;i - 1; ai++) 
      {
      if (i % ai == 0)
        sum1 = sum1 + ai;
      }
  
    for (bj = 1; j - 1; bj++)
      {
      if (j % bj == 0)  
        sum2 = sum2 + bj;
      }
    if ((i == sum2) && (j == sum1))
      printf("%d - %d",i,j);
    else 
      printf("no");
    sum1 = 0;
    sum2 = 0;
  }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: И как вы думаете, сколько времени будет выполняться, например, цикл `for (ai = 1;i - 1; ai++)`? Когда его условие станет ложным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int divsum(int M)
{
    int sum = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= M; ++i)
        if (M%i==0) sum += i + ((M/i != i) ? M/i : 0);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    for(int N = 1; N <= 300; ++N)
    {
        int M = divsum(N);
        if (M >= N)  continue;
        if (divsum(M) == N) printf("%d -- %d\n",M,N);
    }
}
```